# How to remove "&nbsp;" from java string

Tags: java, string, html-entities

I have a java string with `"&nbsp;"` from a text file the program accesses with a Buffered Reader object.  I have tried `string.replaceAll("&nbsp;","")` and it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

```
cleaned = cleaned.replace("&nbsp;"," ");
```

Comment: It definitely works, one of your assumptions must be wrong. How do you finally print that value? How do you check if it works?

Comment: Can we see some more relevant parts of your code?

Comment: It's `string = string.replaceAll(...)`, not simply `string.replaceAll()`.  Strings are immutable, you need to assign it back to a variable just like when you use `replace()` above.

Comment: Why? It must be XML or HTML, i.e. a markup language, so why are you removing the author's markup?

Comment: I solved this problem here. It may be useful for some people in the future.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895601/espresso-assert-text-does-match-but-still-fails/70498424#70498424

Answer (score 124):

```
cleaned = cleaned.replace("\u00a0","")
```

Answer (score 12):

This is a two step process:

```
strLineApp = strLineApp.replaceAll("&"+"nbsp;", " "); 
strLineApp = strLineApp.replaceAll(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ");
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 8):

The same way you mentioned:

```
String cleaned = s.replace("&nbsp;"," ");
```

It works for me.

Comment: @Stephen: I was reluctant to post the entire quote. [It's quite a topic](http://wiki.lspace.org/wiki/Multiple_exclamation_marks)

Comment: Sorry Joachim I didn't see your comment because I tried to answer as quickest as possible to have more points than my colleague.

On a side note I didn't get your comment ???

Comment: @Manuel: never mind me, just a little joke. Read the link in my previous comment, if you want to know more.

Comment: @Joachim. I understand that I must be a little bit crazy with all the multiple exclamation marks I am using, isn't it ???

Answer (score 4):

There's a ready solution to unescape HTML from Apache commons:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("")
```

You can also escape HTML if you want:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can have a regular expression check and replace HTML `nbsp;`

```js
input.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+$", "") + "");
```

It removes non breaking spaces in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable so You need to do

```
string = string.replaceAll("&nbsp;","")
```

Comment: He is already doing that: `cleaned = cleaned.replace("&nbsp;"," ");`

Comment: Take back that -1; if you look at the `replaceAll` example posted in the original post, he's is not clearly already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.replace(char, char)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) takes `char` inputs (or `CharSequence` inputs)

[`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes `String` inputs and matches by regular expression.

For example:

```
String origStr = "bat";
String newStr = str.replace('a', 'i');
// Now:
// origStr = "bat"
// newStr = "bit"
```

The key point is that the return value contains the new edited `String`.  The original `String` variable that invokes `replace()`/`replaceAll()` doesn't have its contents changed.

For example:

```
String origStr = "how&nbsp;are&nbsp;you?";
String newStr = origStr.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," ");
String anotherStr = origStr.replaceAll("&nbsp;","");
// origStr = "how&nbsp;are&nbsp;you?"
// newStr = "how are you?"
// anotherStr = howareyou?"
```

Comment: Note: `String implements CharSequence`.

Comment: Links fixed; they had spaces that needed to be replaced with `%20`.  Usually happens when you copy from your browser after it cleans up the URL to "look nice" instead of copying the raw URL.

Comment: Why isn't anyone stating the obvious mistakes most of these faulty answers are based upon? The method replaceAll() matches by regular expression and replace() matches by equal character(s). This answer should be removed, it's very misleading.

Comment: I think the gist of this is correct. I made a small edit to clarify that `replaceAll()` matches using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/download) library:**

```
String date = doc.body().getElementsByClass("Datum").html().toString().replaceAll("&nbsp;","").trim();
```

Comment: The question is using a BufferedReader not JSoup. The fact is you only need to use String to remove non-breaking spaces. It doesn't matter how you get the String object. JSoup is not required and using it would be a waste of space and time in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the following, and only this worked for me:

```
String string = stringWithNbsp.replaceAll("NNBSP", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

`String`s in Java are immutable. You have to do:

```
String newStr = cleaned.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "");
```

Comment: If you notice, the OP has the replaceAll value being put into a variable - overwriting the original value in the variable.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem: The inner HTML of the element I needed had "&nbsp" and my assertion failed.
Since the question has not accepted any answer,yet I would suggest the following, which worked for me

```
String string = stringwithNbsp.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

P.S : Happy testing :)