# How to clean rss description

Tags: java, android, rss

i m getting `&nbps` in my rss description.How can i clean it?

I m using `.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");` but i m still getting `&nbps` in my text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

> Public Methods
>
> public static Spanned fromHtml (String source)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Returns displayable styled text from the provided
>   HTML string.

```
String str = "YOURHTMLCODEHERE";
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(str);
txtView.setText(spanned);
```

Comment: with the replaceAll i have cleaned my code and i m only getting &nbps inside.May i delete replaceAll and use Spanned?

Comment: super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
       String description = des.get(position).toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");

Comment: ReplaceAll is really a waste of CPU and will make your app slow. Use Html.fromHtml instead ;-)

Comment: Or read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318404/how-to-remove-nbsp-from-java-string

Comment: ok,i replaced it with  Spanned description = Html.fromHtml(des.get(position));

Comment: i m getting the text without html inside ,but whats going on with the images?i m getting some blank boxes...i dont want them

Comment: the boxes are images that the description contains

Comment: So, use Html.fromHtml after you used replaceall... There should be something better but this will work.

Comment: if i use  String description2 = des.get(position).toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");

        Spanned description = Html.fromHtml(description2);

Comment: i clean html tags and the blank boxes but i dont have the html appearance i had before...