# Double asterisk in od -c

Tags: java, terminal

When I run od -c on my textfile, I get something like this

```
0000640    3   6  \n   2   4   :       a   l   u   m   n   i       2   2
0000660    8  \n   2   5   :       a   w   a   r   d       2   2   3  \n
0000700    2   6   :       o   n       2   1   9  \n   2   7   :       h
0000720    a   a   s       2   1   5  \n   2   8   :       7   6   5    
0000740    1   9   5  \n   2   9   :       s       1   9   4  \n   3   0
0000760    :       4   9   4       1   9   3  \n   3   1   :       2   0
0001000    1   6       1   8   3  \n   3   2   :       b   u   i   l   d
0001020    i   n   g       1   8   3  \n   3   3   :       a   n       1
0001040    7   7  \n   3   4   :       d   i   s   t   i   n   g   u   i
0001060    s   h   e   d       1   7   0  \n   3   5   :          **    
0001100    1   6   8  \n   3   6   :       2   0   1   5       1   6   7
0001120   \n   3   7   :       s   t   u   d   e   n   t       1   6   6
0001140   \n   3   8   :       i   s       1   6   2  \n   3   9   :    
0001160    b   y       1   6   0  \n   4   0   :       0   1       1   5
0001200    8  \n   4   1   :       y   o   u       1   5   5  \n   4   2
0001220    :       p   r   o   f   e   s   s   o   r       1   5   3  \n
```

What character is that double asterisk in there? When I open the actual text file, all I see is a blank space.

Also, I wrote this text file using a java print writer. What character is this double asterisk in java

Comment: What operating system are you running `od` on?

Comment: I am running on OS X

Comment: I tested a few non-ASCII cases, but saw no `**` (on OSX and Linux), just octal numbers for the non-ASCII cases.  Perhaps you could see an interesting number if you add the `-t x1` option.

Comment: Here is what I get in the same line  73  68  65  64  20  31  37  30  0a  33  35  3a  20  c2  a0  20

Comment: `a0` is like a blank, but not really (see [description](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)).  Still, I do not see `**` with that character on OSX.  Perhaps it is related to locale.

Comment: How would I go about getting rid of it inside of a String in Java?

Comment: See [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318404/how-to-remove-nbsp-from-java-string)

Comment: @Michael41000 The real question is how did it get *into* the `String`?

Comment: Try `od -xc` to get both hex and character output