# Espresso Assert Text Does Match But Still Fails

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am using Espresso to create a test. The user goes to register screen, inputs details, successfully registers user. User then goes to login screen, inputs username and goes to dashboard. Dashboard has a message which greets the user.

The test runs perfectly fine but fails when checking the dashboard message. It should say "Welcome {user's full name}" which it does. However the error log states it failed:

> android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError:
>   'with text: is "Welcome Jane Doe"' doesn't match the selected view.
>   Expected: with text: is "Welcome Jane Doe"

Here is my test:

```
// Test when user tries to register with alpha numeric character and correct email format, register user. Go to login screen and
// login to the dashboard. Should only display full name
@Test
public void testRegisterWithValidUsernameEmailThenLogin(){
    // register user
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.usernameEditText)).perform(clearText(), typeText(studentFullNameTwo.getUsername()), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.emailEditText)).perform(clearText(), typeText(studentFullNameTwo.getEmail()), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.registerButton)).perform(click());
    // login with new user
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.editTextUsername)).perform(clearText(), typeText(studentFullNameTwo.getUsername()), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.buttonLogin)).perform(click());
    // check welcome header
    String fullName = studentFullNameTwo.getFirstName() + " " + studentFullNameTwo.getLastName();
    // Change view to dashboard screen
    onView(withId(R.id.loggedUserDashHeader)).check(matches(withText("Welcome " + fullName)));
}
```

Comment: Espresso recognize white characters. Mayby there is unbreakable space or some invisible sign somewhere.

Comment: Does your app make any network/database call while logging in? Probably while you try to login and before process of logging in ends, espresso checks if your desired text exists. You need  wait for login to end before asserting your statement

Comment: It does make database calls but only locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have got into this issue last week. It might be late however it may help some people in the future.

I create a variable represent the encoded space.

```
private const val ENCODE_SPACE = '\u00A0'
```

Then, use the encoded space instead an empty string.

```
 "Welcome${ENCODE_SPACE}"
```

In my case, the problem comes an string concatenation from some other parte of the project. It's a reusable code in the project.

Answer (score 0):

As Karol pointed out in his/her comment, it's likely that there is an invisible character somewhere in your view's `"Welcome Jane Doe"` text. Try changing the following assertion...

```kotlin
onView(withId(R.id.loggedUserDashHeader)).check(matches(withText("Welcome " + fullName)));
```

... to include an [equalToCompressingWhiteSpace(expectedString:)](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.1/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#equalToCompressingWhiteSpace-java.lang.String-) call as follows...

```kotlin
onView(withId(R.id.loggedUserDashHeader)).check(matches(withText(equalToCompressingWhiteSpace("Welcome " + fullName))));
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to debug your view to see what characters exactly it contains. Assuming your view is a `Button` or `TextView`, you can do this by calling `myView.text.toString().toCharArray()`.